# List out all resource groups in cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I want to see all the resource groups in my cluster(s). Is there a way to use `az aks` to get all the credentials of the cluster(s) without mentioning the names of the resource-group/cluster?

I tried `az aks get-credentials`, `az aks show`, `az aks list` but they all require the resource group name and I don't know it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I have found a way to list all resources in my azure subscription: `az resource list`. 
I can see some resources here that when i try to find using `az

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After alot of digging, you can find the list of resource groups using this command - `az group list`. 
Note: its useful to go through the `-h` of for `az` to see what it has to offer :)